# A slider to separate 2 content divs

Tags: slider

I want to create an "image comparison slider" for contents. Example:
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/bamf/pen/jEpxOX)

```
// Call & init
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ba-slider').each(function(){
    var cur = $(this);
    // Adjust the slider
    var width = cur.width()+'px';
    cur.find('.resize img').css('width', width);
    // Bind dragging events
    drags(cur.find('.handle'), cur.find('.resize'), cur);
  });
});

// Update sliders on resize. 
// Because we all do this: i.imgur.com/YkbaV.gif
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.ba-slider').each(function(){
    var cur = $(this);
    var width = cur.width()+'px';
    cur.find('.resize img').css('width', width);
  });
});

function drags(dragElement, resizeElement, container) {

  // Initialize the dragging event on mousedown.
  dragElement.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {

    dragElement.addClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.addClass('resizable');

    // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
    var startX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

    // Get the initial position
    var dragWidth = dragElement.outerWidth(),
        posX = dragElement.offset().left + dragWidth - startX,
        containerOffset = container.offset().left,
        containerWidth = container.outerWidth();

    // Set limits
    minLeft = containerOffset + 10;
    maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10;

    // Calculate the dragging distance on mousemove.
    dragElement.parents().on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {

      // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
      var moveX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      leftValue = moveX + posX - dragWidth;

      // Prevent going off limits
      if ( leftValue < minLeft) {
        leftValue = minLeft;
      } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
        leftValue = maxLeft;
      }

      // Translate the handle's left value to masked divs width.
      widthValue = (leftValue + dragWidth/2 - containerOffset)*100/containerWidth+'%';

      // Set the new values for the slider and the handle. 
      // Bind mouseup events to stop dragging.
      $('.draggable').css('left', widthValue).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
      });
      $('.resizable').css('width', widthValue);
    }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function(){
      dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
      resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function(e){
    dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
  });
}
```

Same as above, but instead of images, I want to create content divs with text, images, html. Like 2 pages with a slider to compare both.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison script utilizes a resizing a div, so there's no way (that I know of) to achieve this without some considerable trickery (or how to achieve the same effect without resizing).

The only way to prevent the text from automatically wrapping is by using ...

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

... but that would just result in one continuous line of text.
Breaks `<br>` could be inserted from there, but that would just look awful and negate any resizing.

Personally, my approach would be to render the text within a canvas element first (https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp).

Since a canvas is treated nearly identical to that of an image, it wouldn't require any changes to the existing comparison script.